# Infinite items recyclerview exercise

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a recycler view exercise which is an app with a simple single recycler
that loads pages of size 20 and can hold an infinite amount of items.

Now i don't want to make the naive solution of reloading more and more items, but an elegant
way to use the recycling mechanism to just change items while scrolling.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Recycler`Views already take care of `recycling` and keeps only those entries in memory that are needed. You can put hundreds of items in there without a problem.

[More on that here.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#structure)

> The RecyclerView creates only as many view holders as are needed to
>   display the on-screen portion of the dynamic content, plus a few
>   extra. As the user scrolls through the list, the RecyclerView takes
>   the off-screen views and rebinds them to the data which is scrolling
>   onto the screen.